# How to compute a new variable that is defined by two categorical variables using SPSS?

Tags: spss, data-transformation

I have a questionnaire with a part (a) and part (b). It looks like this:

```
(a) "Do you ever feel sad":  
    0="never", 1="sometime", 2="often", 3="nearly always"
(b) "How distressed are you by this": 
    0="not distressed", 1="a bit distressed", 2="quite distressed", 
    3="very distressed".
```

I want to create a new variable:

```
"Do you feel sad?"
Response: 0="no", but 1="Yes, but no distress", 3="Yes and its distressing".
```

How can I create this new variable using SPSS?

Comment: I voted to close as off topic. There's no statistical question here.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use logical operators and conditionals.

```
part a: 0 1 2 3
part b: 0 1 2 3

Composite:

    0 = (a0)
    1 = ~(a0) & (b0)
    3 = ~(a0) & ~(b0)
```

I haven't tested this, but the SPSS code for computing the composite scores with the outcome 1 would be something like this:

```
DO IF ( (A ~= 0) & (B = 0)).
RECODE A (0=1) INTO C.
END IF.
VARIABLE LABELS C 'Composite'.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: The question addresses coding and data management. Faulty coding (e.g. 1 2 rather than 0 1) can result in poor statistical models for NHST in regression and is of statistical relevance IMHO.

Comment: Daniel thanks for the help, although Im not entirely sure how to implement it. Ill have a go later this evening.

Comment: Use the menu command: Transform/Recode into different variables....
You would have to use this command three times.

Comment: I've had a think about this. On the composite variable for level 1:

Frequency of experience (1="sometime", 2="often", 3="nearly always") + Distress (0="no")

Surely if No is scored as 0 there is no real need to add it since its inclusion to the frequency items will add no information?
So can I recode it as follows?
0 = No
1 = Frequency items (1,2,3) = Yes but not distressing 
2= Yes it is distressing (distress items 1,2,3) since anything over 0 = distress on that scale?

I hope this make sense :/

Comment: You would need to keep 0 as a nominal category, because otherwise you would end up with missing values.  ~= means "not equal to" in SPSS syntax, which makes the code less verbose. If you're not using logic operators, i.e. & , I suggest you check for logical errors in the data first. For example, some might have answered No, I am not sad and it's very distressing.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any difficulties.

Comment: Daniel, have a look, ive done it using this syntax. Thx god!
Apologies, I have no idea how to use the code syntax for this site.
   
    IF  (cape1 = 0) cape_1 = 0.
    IF  (cape1  >=  1 and cape1b = 0) cape_1=1.
    IF  (cape1  >=  1 and cape1b >=  1 ) cape_1=2.
    EXECUTE.

Comment: That looks even better. (I don't think code can be displayed in comments.)